# Use If statement in Excel Solver

Tags: excel, solver

Gone through lot of forums and other resources but couldn't find a solution for the same.

I have a column in excel called `Priority` with 3 unique values 1, 2 and 3 and is shown below

[image]

I want to put a constraint using this column such as:

1. If the value of the cell is 1 then the variable cells should get value no more than 5 but greater than zero
2. If the value of the cell is 2 then the variable cells should get value between 5 - 10
3. If the value of the cell is 3 then the variable cells should get value greater than 10

**Objective**: Is to distribute a number lets say 100 in 9 cells which takes care of the `Priority` condition

How can I do this ?

Comment: How is the problem too broad? the ask is quite straightforward!!

Comment: I think it's interpreted as you asking someone to code your whole project, not having apparently made any effort yourself. If you have tried some code, please post it.

Comment: you had mentioned "If the value of the column is 1 then ..." but in the data you shared is value per row.. not per column.. right?

Comment: @p._phidot_ yes..the value of that particular cell is 1,2 or 3 then the value of the corresponding cell ( the cell which solver will optimize) should be in that range accordingly

Comment: @SJR: That is not the thing actually, I will edit the question and put my efforts also!!

Comment: If 15 is an upper bound for the third condition then your constraints are `5*(cell - 1) < value <= 5*cell`. Without the upper bound in the third case, your best bet might be to make use of a binary decision variable which is constrained in such a way that it takes on the value of 1 exactly when the cell value is 3. Use that variable to bump up the upper bound to say 100 in the third case. It might help if you describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: I'm not sure how solver fit into this.. but are you looking for ways to put `=if(A2=1,RANDBETWEEN(1,5),if(A2=2,RANDBETWEEN(6,10),if(A2=3,RANDBETWEEN(11,1000),"error")))` in a equation that you didn't shown in the question ?